# PHPMailer send mail in xampp but in server linux apache doesn't send mail

Tags: php, apache, email, smtp, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send mails and it works on my xampp, but in my apache server in linux doesn't send mails.

I use a config like this:

```
<?php
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // 1 = errors and messages | 2 = messages only
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    $mail->Host = "smtp ip";
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->Username = $lFrom = "email";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->From=$lFrom; $mail->FromName="name";
?>
```

And my function for send is

```
function enviarEmail($email, $subject, $html, $pNom, $adjuntos, $mail, $imageQR = null, $imageLogo = null,$idDTELog)
  {
    try {
      $mail->clearAddresses(); # limpiando correos
      $mail->clearAttachments(); # limpiando adjuntos acumulados
      $EmailsCopiaOculta = ["email for monitoring results"]; // Desarrollo

      // recorrer direcciones de correo que se enviaran
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($email); $i++) {
        if ($email[$i] == "") {
          continue;
        }
        $mail->addAddress($email[$i]);
      }
      for ($j = 0; $j < count($EmailsCopiaOculta); $j++) {
        $mail->addBCC($EmailsCopiaOculta[$j]);
      }
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($adjuntos); $i++) {
        if ($adjuntos[$i] == "") {
          continue;
        }
        $mail->addAttachment($adjuntos[$i]);
      }

      $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($imageQR, 'qr');
      $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($imageLogo, 'logo');

      $mail->isHTML(true);
      // echo($html);
      $mail->Subject = $subject;
      // $mail->Body = $html;
      $mail->msgHTML($html);
      if (!$mail->send()) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      // return false;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $mail->clearAllRecipients();
      $body = $html;

      // Cargando información del asociado al que no envía
      $html = "
          Nombre Receptor: $pNom
          <br>
          Correos a los que se envía:
          <br>
        ";
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($email); $i++) {
        if ($email[$i] == "") {
          continue;
        }
        $html .= $email[$i] . "<br>";
      }
      $html .= "<br>";

      // Ocurre error, se envia a correo de TI informando
      $mail->addAddress("my personal email");

      $mail->Subject = "Ha ocurrido un error al enviar correo";
      $mail->MsgHTML("<b>DATOS DE DESTINO:</b><br>
                        $html
                        <br>
                        <b>MENSAJE DE ERROR:</b>
                        <br>
                        $e
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        $body");
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->send();
      // Regresa falso para lanzar mensaje a usuario
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Is a new server apache that i make and i know if something is wrong or is something that need the server apache. In XAMPP works fine this code. Please Help!

I need to know if something for configuration in my server apache or is a mistake in my code

Comment: was there any error message? Logs?

Comment: Not return a error message or log :(

Comment: Do you know which part it failed? Did you confirm that the code before the `mailer` works? You have a `try/catch` inside though your `catch` also sends email. Add a log function inside the catch and log `$e->getMessage()` to see what was the error

Comment: Add the log **before** the mailer inside the `catch`